# how to get gridview textbox control id in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Currently I'm working on gridview it's have textbox on submit click I want to get textbox id of gridview but I an unable to find it button submit.
Could anybody help me get the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use following example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtNameID = '<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get real control's id with `ClientID` property and use `OnClientClick` for button which you can create during data binding.

Simple example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/cal.gif" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ImageButton1.OnClientClick = "openCalendar(" + TextBox1.ClientID + ", " + X.ToString() + ", " + Y.ToString() + ");return false;";
}
```

Comment: but i want to get this id through javascript code not in c# page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ID you really want to find, where the textbox/submit button is located(in gridview?) and why you need client script(perhaps there is a better way). Please  supply some code.

You can get the javascript objects with DOM f.e. with [nextSibling](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_nextsibling.asp).
So you even dont need an ID.